# using the same UIDatePicker for two different UITextFields to input different dates

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have a XIB file that contains a UIDatePicker.  I added it to my UI as a subview. It appears and functions perfectly but when I try to input the date it doesn't do that.

Here is the method I used to set the text to equal the date entered in the DatePicker:

```
-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{
    myDatePicker = [[myDatePickerView subviews] lastObject];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:sender.locale];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
}
```

I removed the code that sets the text because it doesn't work.  I tried everything and it still doesn't work.

P.S: No editing session is started in the TextFields because I don't want the keyboard to appear.

Answer (score 0):

-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{

```
//You get the date piker object directly from sender.

//Some how, your date format is in a specific format like this: "DD-MM-YYYY" Convert the input string to Data using NSDateFormatter, like this.

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:sender.locale];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD-MM-YYYY"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12-04-2013"];

[sender setDate:date];//here sender is your datePicker, and we are setting the date to that.
```

}